# How I can make the diagram tree more perfect?

Tags: beamer, diagrams, tikz-trees, forest

[image]

I want to make this diagram more perfect in beamer.

I want be similar to this style

[image]

Can someone help me

I used this to make this diagram

```
\forestset{
    L1/.style={fill=blue!20,},
    L2/.style={fill=blue!20,edge={black,line width=1pt}},
    L3/.style={fill=blue!20,edge={black,line width=1pt}},
    L4/.style={fill=blue!20,edge={black,line width=1pt}},
}


     \begin{forest}
     for tree={
        grow=0,reversed, % tree direction
        parent anchor=east,child anchor=west, % edge anchors
        edge={line cap=round},outer sep=+2pt, % edge/node connection
        rounded corners,minimum width=15mm,minimum height=8mm, % node shape
        l sep=18mm % level distance
     }
     [Association Scheme,L1
     [Bose and Nair,L2
     [1939,L3
     ]]
    [Bose and Shimamoto,L2
    [1952,L3
    ]]
     ]
    \end{forest}


\
   \begin{forest}
    for tree={
        grow=0,reversed, % tree direction
        parent anchor=east,child anchor=west, % edge anchors
        edge={line cap=round},outer sep=+2pt, % edge/node connection
        rounded corners,minimum width=15mm,minimum height=8mm, % node shape
        l sep=20mm % level distance
    }
    [Bose-Mesner algebra,L1
    [Bose  and Mesner,L2
    [1959,L3
    ]]
    ]
   \end{forest}

   \forestset{
    L1/.style={fill=blue!20,},
    L2/.style={fill=blue!20,edge={black,line width=1pt}},
    L3/.style={fill=blue!20,edge={black,line width=1pt}},
    L4/.style={fill=blue!20,edge={black,line width=1pt}},
   }
   \begin{forest}
    for tree={
        grow=0,reversed, % tree direction
        parent anchor=east,child anchor=west, % edge anchors
        edge={line cap=round},outer sep=+2pt, % edge/node connection
        rounded corners,minimum width=15mm,minimum height=8mm, % node shape
        l sep=20mm % level distance
    }
    [Coherent Configuration,L1
    [D. G. Higman,L2
    [1967,L3
    ]]
    ]
   \end{forest}
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: The second diagram, although formally a tree, isn't really displayed in the way trees are usually displayed. If you want to draw a diagram like that, `forest` may not be the best solution.

Comment: It isn't clear how the information in your trees can be represented in the circular structure shown. That is, it isn't clear what it would mean to present that content in that way.

Comment: Also, please make your code compilable.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to emulate the structure, you need to explain how the content in your diagram should map to that structure. Forest probably is not a good choice in that case.

If you want the nodes and arrows etc. to look more like those in the image, you might try something like this:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{beamer}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\forestset{
  my tree/.style={
    forked edges,
    for tree={
      grow'=0,
      fork sep=5mm,
      drop shadow,
      anchor=parent,
      edge={draw=DarkOrchid3, -Latex, thick},
      l sep'=7.5mm,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      tempcounta/.max={level()-1}{tree},
      for tree={
        top color/.wrap pgfmath arg={blue!##1!WildStrawberry!50}{((level()-1)/(tempcounta))*100)},
        bottom color/.wrap pgfmath arg={blue!##1!WildStrawberry}{((level()-1)/(tempcounta))*100)},
        draw/.wrap pgfmath arg={blue!##1!WildStrawberry}{((level()-1)/(tempcounta))*100)},
        text=white,
        tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier ##1}{level()},
        content/.wrap value={\strut ##1},
      }
    },
    where level=0{phantom}{},
  }
}

\begin{frame}
\begin{forest}
  my tree
  [
   [Association Scheme
   [Bose and Nair
   [1939
   ]]
  [Bose and Shimamoto
  [1952
  ]]
   ]
  [Bose-Mesner algebra
  [Bose  and Mesner
  [1959
  ]]
  ]
  [Coherent Configuration
  [D. G. Higman
  [1967
  ]]
  ]]
\end{forest}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: fancier nodes and stuff]